# zend 2: Trying to pass around a ViewModel between methods

Tags: templates, zend-framework2

I spent a little while trying to figure out how to implement a sub menu bar and eventually decided all I really want is a little helper method that appends my template to the current view instead of an actual view helper:

```
//To use in any action requiring the sub navbar to be displayed
protected function addSubNav(ViewModel $view) {
    $subNavView = new ViewModel();
    $subNavView->setTemplate('helpdesk/helpdesk/subNav');
    $view->addChild($subNavView, 'subNav');

    return $view;
}
```

But when I call it in a method like this $this->subNav in my template is null:

```
public function indexAction() {
    //return new ViewModel();
    $this->addSubNav(new ViewModel());
}
```

When doing $this->subNav in index.phtml is NULL, why is that?

addSubNav() should be returning the view which I appended a template to.

Comment: you're not returning the result of calling your helper method in your action, it should be `return $this->addSubNav(new ViewModel());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return your view model a the end of your action

```
public function indexAction() {
    return $this->addSubNav(new ViewModel());
}
```

Comment: Well I feel silly. I guess I was thinking that because the function being called returns the view it would just pass it along to calling function, but of course it doesn't work like that.